# How to screenshot noxplayer?

Tags: autohotkey

Are there any available tool or soft can do that ?

mikeyww help me with ahk but it seem nox block it or not right ahk_class
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=121434&p=539082#p539082

```
/* Timed window screenshot ------------------------------------------------------
This script uses GDI+ to save screenshots of a window (foreground or background)
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=121434&p=539053#p539053
https://github.com/marius-sucan/AHK-GDIp-Library-Compilation
By mikeyww • For AutoHotkey version 1.1.37.01
14 September 2023
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.33
#Include d:\Q\vis2\lib\Gdip_All.ahk
winTitle := "ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon"      ; Target window
dir      := A_ScriptDir              ; Output directory for images
freq     := 1000                     ; Frequency (ms) of image capture
pToken   := Gdip_Startup()
OnExit("done")                       ; Clean up upon exit

#If WinExist(winTitle)
F3::                                 ; F3 = Toggle timer for screenshots
If on := !on {
 SetTimer Capture, % freq            ; Schedule for image capture
 SoundBeep 1500
 Gosub Capture
 Return
}
Stop:
SetTimer Capture, Off
SoundBeep 1000
on := False
Return
#If

Capture:
If hWnd := WinExist(winTitle) {                         ; Get target window's HWND
 pBitmap := Gdip_BitmapFromHWND(hWnd)                   ; Get window's bitmap
 FormatTime ts,, yyMMdd-HHmmss                          ; Use timestamp in file name
 Gdip_SaveBitmapToFile(pBitmap, dir "\image" ts ".png") ; Save image file
 SoundBeep 2500
} Else Gosub Stop                                       ; Stop timer when window does not exist
Return

done(exitReason, exitCode) {
 If pBitmap
  Gdip_DisposeImage(pBitmap)
 Gdip_Shutdown(pToken)
 SoundBeep 1000
}
```